# Getting this PHP error, but getting the correct output?

Tags: php, drupal

So I am trying to run some PHP code inside of Drupal (inside of a node, with PHP code parsing enabled).

I'm trying to get the data from a field, in this case a simple text field.

I am getting that information displayed, but also this error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value' in eval() (line 8 of /hermes/waloraweb033/b418/moo.arao1989/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value' in eval() (line 8 of /hermes/waloraweb033/b418/moo.arao1989/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
```

My code is as follows:

```
<?

if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
$test = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_testvalue');

$supertest = $test[0];

echo $supertest[value];

} ?>
```

Ah, I ask dumb questions sometimes.

Comment: Try `echo $supertest['value']`?

Comment: well for a start a "notice" is not an error, the only issues is the missing quotes for the array key

Comment: `echo $supertest[value];` --> `echo $supertest['value'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need strings when you reference array keys in an associative array:

```
echo $supertest['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this edit and you should be good.
`echo $supertest['value'];`

Edit: Seems it has already been answered

Comment: change it to what? did you read the comments and other answers, posted before posting?